# Removing newline char from string on upload

Tags: mysql, sql, load-data-infile

Created a new table using the following:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/new_tbl_1.csv' 
INTO TABLE tbl_1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
```

I've found that I can't join on the final column of this table because there is an additional character being added.

For example if I check `length(field_1)` on a record that says 'Blue', it will return a length of 4, unless it's the last field in the table, in which case it returns a length of 5.

When copying the visible record and pasting into a spreadsheet, it pastes like this:
`'Blue\r'`

Am I uploading incorrectly? How can I account for this line break so that it doesn't break the `JOIN`?

Comment: It's a CR character. Change `\n` to `\r\n`

Comment: @Barmar beautiful. Any help understanding why it's added, and when to to use both \r\n?

Comment: It's not added, it's in the file.

Comment: On Windows, CRLF is the normal line break sequence.

Comment: Windows style - NewLine is `'\r\n'`. Unix style - NewLine is `'\n'`. Anycase [input preprocessing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-input-preprocessing) may take this into account and remove excess `'\r'` if present.

Comment: And a filename beginning with `C:` tells me that you're on Windows.

Comment: @Akina ty sir. That helps. I must've misread the documentation on this.

Comment: This is a style for text files which is not related to MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comments have pointed out, on windows, instead of: `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` it requires the additional `\r` like: `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`